# the lowest positive integer number

Tags: number-theory

For each positive integer number  $n$  is denoted by $p (n)$ the number of perfect squares nonzero, at most equal to $n$ and $S_n = p (1)+ p (2)+ p (3)\cdots+ p (n)$.

a) Calculate $S_{17}$

b) Determine the lowest positive integer number $n$ for which $S_n > 2017$

If you can, please give me some advice because I do not know how to determine the general term. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, how to determine the general term?Thanks!

Comment: Looking at your posting history, you have a habit of posting questions with no effort shown.  This is why your questions are constantly being closed.  This one should be closed for the same reason.

Comment: Voting to close the question.  If you can, edit your post to indicate what you have tried and where you are getting stuck.

Comment: There are 3 positive integers whose square root is $\geq{1}$ and $<2$, there are $5$ whose square root is $\geq{2}$ and $<3$, and so on. Can I find a pattern? Can I use the fact that $(n+1)^2-n^2=2n+1$ to prove this pattern? Finally, can I use this pattern to help find $S_n$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$p(n) = \lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor$

So, $p(1)=1, p(2)=1, p(3)=1, p(4)=2, p(5)=2, p(6)=2, p(7)=2, \ldots$.

Let's look at the pattern here:
$S_1 = 1$,
$S_2 = 2$,
$S_3 = 3$,
$S_4 = 5$,
$S_5 = 7$,
$S_6 = 9$,
$S_7 = 11$,
$S_8 = 13$,
$S_9 = 16$,
$S_{10} = 19$,
$S_{11} = 22$,
$S_{12} = 25$,
$S_{13} = 28$,
$S_{14} = 31$,
$S_{15} = 34$,
$S_{16} = 38$,
$S_{17} = 42$

Essentially, $S_n = \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor}(n-k^2+1) = n-\dfrac{1}{6}\left(\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor -1 \right) \left( 2\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor^2+5\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor - 6n \right)$

So, $S_{17} = 42$.

I leave part (b) to you.